# looping through multidimensional array innermost loop

Tags: javascript

I am ultimately trying to create a function that generates some html based on values in a two dimensional(?) array. However, I am struggling to loop through all of the values. In the following code, it is the bottom `else` clause that my program never enters:

```
let food = [
  [
    'Wedges',
    ['Hero Wedge', "Lettuce, tomato, yada", '$19.42'],
    ['Differebt Wedge', "Chicken, tomato, yada", '$12.42'],
  ],
  [
    'Chicken',
    ['Chicken', "Lettuce, tomato, yada", '$19.42'],
    ['Brocolli Wedge', "Chicken, tomato, yada", '$12.42'],
  ]
]
generate(food);

function generate(food){
  for(i = 0; i < food.length; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < food[i].length; j++){
      if(j === 0){
        sectionName = food[i][j]; // "Wedges"
      }
      else{
        for(y = 0; y < food[i][j]; y++){
          console.log("were in this statment"); //Never runs
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When `i = 0` and `j = 1` 
doesn't 
    `food[i][j] = ['Hero Wedge', "Lettuce, tomato, yada", '$19.42']` ? And since this is an array with 3 elements `y < food[i][j]` should evaluate to true? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `y < food[i][j]` -> `y < food[i][j].length`?

Comment: ..... you have no idea how long I was trying to figure out what was wrong before coming to stackoverflow. But thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the length of the array and declare all variables.

```
for(y = 0; y < food[i][j].length; y++){ // use length
```

A better approach by iteration from one instead of zero and without a check.

```js
function generate(food) {
    var i, j, y, sectionName;
    for (i = 0; i < food.length; i++) {
        sectionName = food[i][0];                     // assign outside of the loop
        console.log('sectionName', sectionName);
        for (j = 1; j < food[i].length; j++) {        // start from one
            for (y = 0; y < food[i][j].length; y++) { // use length
                console.log(food[i][j][y]);
            }
        }
    }
}

let food = [['Wedges', ['Hero Wedge', "Lettuce, tomato, yada", '$19.42'], ['Different Wedge', "Chicken, tomato, yada", '$12.42']], ['Chicken', ['Chicken', "Lettuce, tomato, yada", '$19.42'], ['Brocolli Wedge', "Chicken, tomato, yada", '$12.42']]];

generate(food);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `for` loop is ranging from  `y = 0` to `y` being less than the element at `food[i][j]` instead of the length of `food[i][j]`.

Where `food[i][j]` is `"wedges"`

So, basically, your `for` loop would translate to `for(y = 0; y < "wedges"; y++){`

Hence, replace `food[i][j]` in the `for` with `food[i][j].length`, making the loop as

```
else{
    for(y = 0; y < food[i][j].length; y++) { //take the length of food[i][j]
       console.log("were in this statement"); //Now runs
    }
}
```

This should solve your issue.